# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Kad Matrik='DDWC2017/060550

Tags: vb.net

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Kad Matrik='DDWC2017/060550 its that only problem then i dont how solve this coding

```
   Dim strName = MatrikTextBox.Text

        With objCon
            .Close()
            If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                .ConnectionString = strConnection
                .Open()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please Insert the correct Kad Matrik", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End If

        End With

        ds.Clear()
        strSQL = "Select * from DaftarMasukPelajar where Kad Matrik='" & MatrikTextBox.Text
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, objCon)
        da.Fill(ds, "DaftarMasukPelajar")

        If ds.Tables("DaftarMasukPelajar").Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            MaximizeBox = True
            MinimizeBox = True
            MsgBox("Hello! " + strName + vbNewLine +
                   "Log in successful", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly,
                   "Welcome " + strName)
            Form4.ShowDialog()
            If Form4.Visible Then
                Me.Hide()
            End If
```

Comment: The answer is already inside the error message you are being given! You are missing the closing quote on the string `'DDWC2017/060550`.  Look in your code: You add a single-quote at the start but you don't put one at the end.

Comment: In addition, parsing a string directly into your SQL invites SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  You should switch to using a parameterised query (although that is beyond the scope of your question)

Comment: Also, if Kad Matrik is a column name then you need to put brackets around it since there's a space in it

Answer (score 1):

```
    With objCon
        .Close()
        If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            .ConnectionString = strConnection
            .Open()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Insert the correct Kad Matrik", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    End With
```

This first bit of code doesn't make sense. You close the connection then check if it is closed and open it. Of course it is closed so the Else will never run. In any event, what  would the corred Kad Matrik have to do with the connection being closed?

```
        Form4.ShowDialog()
        If Form4.Visible Then
            Me.Hide()
        End If
```

Why would you check if Form4 is visible when the line before shows it?

To validate a user you don't need a dataset and a dataadapter, just a command and a connection.

It is a good idea to keep your database code separate from the user interface code. The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. Keep these objects local to the procedure and don't open the connection until the last possible minute, right before the .Execute...

Don't retrieve more data than you need. Don't Select * when all you need is to know if the record exists.

```
Private strConnection As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function ValidateUser(Matrik As String) As Boolean
    Dim ReturnValue As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DaftarMasukPelajar WHERE [Kad Matrik] = @KadMatrik;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@KadMatrik", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Matrik
            cn.Open()
            ReturnValue = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If ReturnValue = 1 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ValidateUser(MatrikTextBox.Text) Then
        MaximizeBox = True
        MinimizeBox = True
        MsgBox("Hello! " & MatrikTextBox.Text & vbNewLine &
               "Log in successful", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly,
               "Welcome " & MatrikTextBox.Text)
        Form4.ShowDialog()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, invalid login")
    End If
End Sub
```